# Token replacement pattern for triggered rules on node creation

Tags: 6, rules, tokens

I am currently using triggered rules to send notifications whenever a certain node type is created (by anonymous, unauthenticated users). In the email notification sent I would like to include some of the content submitted in the form but I cannot find any of the replacements tokens when editing the ruleset for the event.

Right now, the token replacement patters for Form and for Form State are listed as empty.

How can I get hold of the relevant replacement tokens for the Form content?

Is there any modules that are capable of sending similar notifications (with node/Form content) upon node creation?

I am using Drupal 6.20, Rules 6.x-1.4, Token 6.x-1.15, CCK 6x.2.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be possible with the the above modules.

You do not need to get data from the form/form_state.

I'm assuming the data you want is from a cck field because you're sending the email when a new node is created.

Rules has the "Replacement patterns for saved content" field set for pattens.

In there there's going to be cck specific token replacements. You can use those cck tokens to get the data you want.

These replacement tokens will look like [node:field_name_of_your_field-formatted]

Also make sure you're using the "After saving new content" event.